# character-set-server VS default-character-set in MySQL

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

What's the difference between `character-set-server` and `default-character-set` in `my.cnf`? I want to set MySQL's connection to UTF8 and both of these seem to work. Is one better than the other?

Answer (score 1):

Always use

```
character-set-server
```

> The server character set and collation are used as default values if the database character set and collation are not specified in CREATE DATABASE statements. They have no other purpose ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-server.html))

`character-set-server` has replaced `default-character-set` setting, since `default-character-set` is now [deprecated](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52047) and can cause [problems](http://www.justinball.com/2011/07/05/upgrade-to-mysql-5-5-12-and-now-mysql-wont-start/).

p.s. I believe the answer by [newtover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68998/newtover) is wrong.

Comment: my answer is not wrong, but outdated. And this answer is misleading. I updated my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-configuration.html):

> You can force client programs to use specific character set as follows:
>
> ```
> [client]
> default-character-set=charset_name
> ```
>
> This is normally unnecessary. However, when `character_set_system` differs from `character_set_server` or `character_set_client`, and you input characters manually (as database object identifiers, column values, or both), these may be displayed incorrectly in output from the client or the output itself may be formatted incorrectly. In such cases, starting the mysql client with `--default-character-set=system_character_set`—that is, setting the client character set to match the system character set—should fix the problem.

In other words, `character_set_server` and `character_set_client` are settings for `mysqld`, when `default-character-set` is a setting for `mysql` and other client libraries which overrides `character_set_client` assumed by `mysqld` by default.

You may not see the difference if you connect with `mysql` to localhost, but `default-character-set` is used as well when you connect to some other server, which may have other defaults.

**UPD from 2018-08-17**

As John Smith noticed, my answer is currently outdated, but the essence of it is still correct: `character_set_server` is a server variable, but when you connect to the mysqld with a client, you should specify the client and connection settings.

In these days much many computers used as clients and servers have `utf-8` as a default for locale encoding and only because of that setting `character-set-server` instead of `default-character-set` might seem to work.

To be clear, to set up mysqld (that is server) to use `utf-8` and some its collation as default for schema names, table names, column names and column values instead of `latin1_swedish_ci` you should set up `characted-set-server` in mysqld configuration.

But when you connect a mysql client to the server, your current charset may be any other, and to correctly convert to the server character set the data you send over a connection and to convert back the data sent from the server as response, you should specify the corresponding [client settings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html):

> ```
> SET character_set_client = charset_name;
> SET character_set_results = charset_name;
> SET character_set_connection = charset_name;
> ```

or the corresponding settings in mysql.ini for your client application. If all of them are the same, you can start your communication with server with a shorter statement:

> ```
> SET NAMES 'charset_name' [COLLATE 'collation_name'];
> ```